# Interpolating missing values for time series based on the values of the same period from a different year

Tags: python, time-series, interpolation

I have a time series like the following:

```
date        value
2017-08-27  564.285714
2017-09-03  28.857143
2017-09-10  NaN
2017-09-17  NaN
2017-09-24  NaN
2017-10-01  236.857143
... ...
2018-09-02  345.142857
2018-09-09  288.714286
2018-09-16  274.000000
2018-09-23  248.142857
2018-09-30  166.428571
```

It corresponds to that ranging from July 2017 to November 2019 and it's resampled by weeks. However, there are some weeks where the values were 0. I replaced it as there the values were missing and now I would like to feel those values based on values on the homologous period of a different year. For example, I have a lot of data missing for the month of September of 2017. I would like to interpolate those values using the values from September 2018. However, I'm a newbie and I'm not quite sure I to do it based only on a select period. I'm working in python, btw.

If anyone has any idea on how to this quickly, I'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: you can read your data into a pandas dataframe and then use tools such as `pandas.DataFrame.loc[index - <period>]` and `pandas.DataFrame.fillna()` . Please have a look at the pandas documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/overview.html

Comment: Can you edit the sample data with October-2018 and October-2017 ?

Comment: @PrinceFrancis done (and it was actually September, sorry about that, already changed it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with `pandas` library
One option is to find the `week` number from `date` and fill NaN values.

```py
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime("%V")
df2 = df.sort_values(['week']).fillna(method='bfill').sort_values(['date'])
df2
```

which will give you the following output.

```
    date    value   week
0   2017-08-27  564.285714  34
1   2017-09-03  28.857143   35
2   2017-09-10  288.714286  36
3   2017-09-17  274.000000  37
4   2017-09-24  248.142857  38
5   2017-10-01  236.857143  39
6   2018-09-02  345.142857  35
7   2018-09-09  288.714286  36
8   2018-09-16  274.000000  37
9   2018-09-23  248.142857  38
10  2018-09-30  166.428571  39
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['value_last_year'])
```